# mongo db query output needs in format

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Using below query:

```
db.logins.aggregate([ 
 { $match:{"$and":  [{"agentRole": {"$in": ["ds_se_t","se_bt_tec","ne_bs_tec","fe_bs_tec"]}},
 {"loginLogoutTime": {"$gte": ISODate("2020-10-25T00:00:00.000"),"$lt": ISODate("2020-10-25T20:00:00.000-0400")}}]}}, 
 { $group: {_id: {Dates: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$loginLogoutTime" }} } ,
 uniqueCount: {$addToSet: "$Uid"}, User: {$addToSet: "$Uid"} }}, 
 { $project: {  "_id" : NumberInt(0),   "Dates" : "$_id.Dates", "TOTALUSERS" : {$size:"$uniqueCount"}, "Uid" : "$User" }}

 ])
```

output is showing like:

```
 {
    "Dates" : "2020-10-25",
    "TOTALUSERS" : 7,
    "Uid" : [ 
        "ab179", 
        "ca973", 
        "dg1212", 
        "pb9317", 
        "fc9875", 
        "bs1967", 
        "de1987", 
 
    ]
}
```

we need the output in format, in csv file, there are only 7 records from above json query

```
TOTALUSERS  :7
    Dates                Uid
    
    10/25/2020        ab179
    10/25/2020        ca973  
    10/25/2020        dg1212
    10/25/2020        pb9317
    10/25/2020        fc9875
    10/25/2020        bs1967
    10/25/2020        de1987
```

How can we achieve above result? What we need to amend in query to get this output?

Comment: Json to tabular format? Or array to String?

Comment: yes output in csv file we are storing in csv file output should be like above:-10/25/2020  7      ab179,ca973,dg1212,pb9317,fc9875,bs1967,de1987  and from second row again 10/25/2020  7      ab179,ca973,dg1212,pb9317,fc9875,bs1967,de1987   like wise till 7 rows above

Comment: Json we are using above query...what modification we need to do get required result.

Comment: You want output of 7 identical rows? Sounds bit strange...

Comment: Thanks James, I updated my requested output thanks.

Comment: Experts, any advise please.

Comment: please provide sample data